# Fetching a Facebook page's events?

Tags: facebook, api, events

I am trying to fetch a Facebook page's events. I have before, but it doesnt work any more. I used this scriptto fetch the events.

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/?$pageids&fields=events.limit($fblimit)&access_token=$token&method=GET");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

$pageids was a lot of different facebook ids (id1,id2,id2 ...)

I get this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: events.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my script? Is there a another way to fetch Facebook events?

Answer (score 0):

The actual URL to get a page's events is something like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events
```

I'm not sure how old the code is that you are fixing, but this is the correct method as stated in the documentation. `events` is a connection of the `page` object.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has had restricted access of Events in API recently.
You have to do app review to have access to Pages API, Events API.
Please check section "Apps that Require App Review, Business Verification, and Supplemental Terms" of this url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: Actually it looks like Facebook has not yet decided what will be required to access the page events edge. Today https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/ says: "This edge is only available to a limited number of approved apps. Unapproved apps querying this edge will receive an empty data set in response. You cannot request access to this edge at this time."